# Actionmailer does not work when used with proxy server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, smtp, smtpproxy

Below are my smtp settings:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address        => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port           => 587,
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name      => 'username@gmail.com',
  :password       => 'password',
  :domain         => 'gmail.com'
}

ActionMailer::Base.mail(
  :from => 'username@gmail.com', 
  :to => 'username@gmail.com', 
  :subject => "Test Mail", 
  :body => "This is a test email"
).deliver
```

It works on my system(i.e. without proxy).
But this same smtp settings does not work on proxy server. I have set http_proxy and https_proxy on proxy server.
But It throws below error at the time of sending mail-

> Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired

Comment: Did anyone find the solution for this?